# MEF open generic problems with 4.5 convention api

Tags: generics, mef, convention

MEF in .NET Framework 4.5 support generic types exports, it works in attribute way:

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(Interface1<>))]
public interface Interface1<T>
{

}

public class Type1 : Interface1<string>
{

}
```

The export object can be resolved:

```
AssemblyCatalog cat = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly, builder);
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(cat);

var o = container.GetExportedValue<Interface1<string>>();
```

But why it does not work use convention base API:

```
RegistrationBuilder builder = new RegistrationBuilder();

builder.ForType<Type1>().Export(it => it.AsContractType(typeof(Interface1<>)).Inherited());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want the container to create an object by it's interface. But you're crating a rule for the specific type:

```
builder.ForType<Type1>()
```

That works if you want to do this:

```
container.GetExportedValue<Type1>();
```

What you need to do is create a rule for this generic interface:

```
    builder.ForTypesMatching(t =>
        {
            return t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Interface1<>));
        })
        .ExportInterfaces();
```